# What is the part number for a SIO connector?

Tags: serial, connector, components, rs232, identification

What actually is an [Atari SIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_SIO) connector, if I wanted to order the part? I have tried Farnell for DB13, Dsub 13 etc but no joy. I am assembling a [SIO2ST](http://mixinc.net/atari/pinouts/stxl.htm) for an [800XL](http://www.atarimuseum.com/computers/8BITS/XL/800xl/800xl.htm).

[image: Cable]

Comment: Without a picture or drawing you're not likely to get a answer.

Comment: Here is a pinout http://www.mixinc.net/atari/pinouts/sio.htm tho' a link to Wikipedia and to the board I want to build, I thought wouldn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: That appears to be a "DB" connector, but 13 pins is unusual. Try looking for something called a "DB-13". Nowadays you find mostly DB-9, and old serial ports were usually DB-15. As for the page you linked to, I did take a look but there was no picture or drawing there either. Perhaps it linked to one, but we shouldn't have to go digging like that. That's your job.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have had no luck finding a DB-13, hence my question that it might be known by another name.

Comment: Ordering? This looks like a custom designed connector for a computer that went out of production 30 years ago. Unlikely that anybody still makes those. I suggest you contact an Atari user group, which may have spare parts from cannibalized computers.

Comment: Well, you can still get the DB9 and 15 easily enough, but I fear you might be right. I just wanted to know if DB13 is the right name for it.

Comment: DB9 and DB15 are old but they're still used today: the video in the PC I bought this week has a DB15 connector next to the DVI. The one on the photo is not a DB13. Olin was probably mislead by the simplified drawing which just shows the staggered pinout. On the photo it doesn't look anything like a DB.

Comment: I wonder about whipping the socket out of the 800XL and soldering a DB15 in its place. Might need to modify the case a bit I suppose. But I don't even intend to connect a real Atari disk drive to this box.

Comment: Now that you finally show a picture, it is clear these are not "DB" connectors.  I don't think I've ever seen anything quite like that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the owner of the site you linked to (SIO2ST schematic http://mixinc.net/atari/pinouts/stxl.htm ).  This connector is indeed a proprietary one, only used on the Atari 8-Bit line of computers (400/800/XL/XE).

However these connectors are still available from a few sources (like BEST Electronics or B&C Computervision) many people choose to mount such an interface into the Atari itself and just connect the few wires to the internal side of the SIO chassis.  You can use a DB9 chassis and make a hole exactly above the SIO chassis to fit the DB9.  Wire it in a way so you can use a standard modem cable to make the connection between the Atari XL and Atari ST.

Answer (score 1):

It's proprietary.

You may have some luck via [Best Electronics](http://www.best-electronics-ca.com/) (apologies for the gaudiness of the linked site) since they seem to have tons of old Atari inventory.

Answer (score 1):

Part number is CX-81 for the 5-foot cable. There is also a 3-foot and a 1-foot cable part number; see http://www.best-electronics-ca.com/
B&C Computervisions also stock there.

You can also obtain the SIO connector plugs from both sources (email for this; not published online).

As others have stated, these are proprietary plugs and are NOS (new old stock) or used. So far, nobody has generated free 3D printer models for these, sadly.

If you are semi-permanently connecting these, I would skimp on the cable and just use female to male jumper wires soldered to a pair of Ethernet cables (tho the SIO cables are cheap...).

Also see: http://whizzosoftware.com/sio2arduino/

Comment: BTW, the USB standard is inspired by the Atari SIO bus from 1979. It's much easier to design peripherals to a single serial-based standard, and folks like Lothrotek.pl are still designing or adapting hardware for it.